# Connecting and migrating .net core web app to digital ocean managed database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have created a .net core 2.1 web app and I want to migrate my database to Digital Ocean Managed Database. I am doing this locally on my laptop in my IDE by using the Database connection string provided by Digital Ocean.

> C:\Users\username\source\repos\Pojects\Web\appname\appname>dotnet ef database update

After the above statement I get This error:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported:
>   postgresql://databasename:password@database-db-do-user-660-0.db.ondigitalocean.com:25/ddb?sslmode
>   Parameter name: keyword    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword) in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line
>   244    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String
>   keyword, Object value) in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line
>   172    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)    at
>   Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>   in
>   C:\projects\npgsql-entityframeworkcore-postgresql\src\EFCore.PG\Storage\Internal\NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.cs:line
>   209    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action)
>
> Keyword not supported:
>   postgresql://database:passssword@database-db-do-user-660-0.db.ondigitalocean.com:2/ddb?sslmode
>   Parameter name: keyword

Please I want to know if what I am doing is right.

Now, my question.

1. I want to know how to connect to my database on Digital Ocean managed database
2. How to deploy .net app to digital ocean droplet and connect to the database

Answer (score 2):

1. > System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: postgresql://databasename:password@database-db-do-user-660-0.db.ondigitalocean.com:25/ddb?sslmode Parameter name: keyword

   This kind of error is typically caused by an incorrect connection string. 
   Quoted from the [DO's docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to/connect/) :

   > *the general format is `postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/database`*

   Note this is not [standard postgresql connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/) that can be directly used by `EFCore`. You need change your connection string as below:

   ```
   User ID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=database-db-do-user-660-0.db.ondigitalocean.com;Port=25;Database=ddb;Pooling=true;
   ```
2. > How to deploy .net app to digital ocean droplet and connect to the database

   Quoted from [DO's docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/):

   > *DigitalOcean Droplets are **Linux-based virtual machines (VMs)** that run on top of virtualized hardware*

   In other words, you need

   1. Follow the Microsoft's docs to [publish your WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app)
   2. Copy your published App files to your remote server. For example, using the `scp` command: `scp your-file-dir user@your-host:/path`
   3. Follow DO's docs to [connect the server](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/quickstart/#connect-to-droplets)
   4. Setting up [a reverse proxy (Nginx/Apache2, etc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server)
   5. [Run your dotnet webApp as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#create-the-service-file)